# Pegar valores XML com PHP

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<pais>
    <estado tipo="RJ">
        <bairro nome="listar">
            <local>
                <aparecer>Flamengo</aparecer>
            </local> 
            <local>
                <aparecer>Botafogo</aparecer>
            </local> 
             <local>
                <aparecer>Urca</aparecer>
            </local> 
       </bairro>
    </estado>
</pais>
```

E pegando com o PHP dessa forma:

```
$arquivo = "bairros.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivo);

foreach ($xml->estado->bairro as $listar) {
    echo $listar->local->aparecer;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Ele só me retorna o primeiro bairro e não todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere seu foreach para:

```
foreach ($xml->estado->bairro->local as $listar) {
    echo $listar->aparecer;
}
```

Comment: Bingo William. Obrigado!